# How to calculate receiving shadow?

Tags: cesiumjs

Using the Cesium library, I want to find shadows that objects fall onto each other. With Cesium, I can create shadows of objects, but I have no idea how to get the shadows that fall on objects. How can I calculate the amount of shadows or amount of light falling on objects?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to find each pixel's color or brightness. Maybe you can find something on this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24662/detect-lightshadow-falling-on-object.html). I don't know how to do it on Cesium.